# Only add modified files in current dir with git?

Tags: git, version-control

Simple question. How can I just add modified and tracked files in the current directory to the repository ?

Suppose I have 3 modified files.

```
Utils/readme.txt
code/main.pas
code/feature.pas
```

The current dir is in code/. So I want to commit only main.pas and feature.pas file.

Comment: You have used both the words `commit` and `add`, which in `git` have very different meanings and functions. The answer to your question will depend upon the exact state of the repository - to be precise, the exact state of the files of interest in the repository. `To commit` only modified files to the repository is different from `to add`. Answers given so far only deal with how to `add` only modified files to the `staging` area of the repository. They still need to be committed after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

`git add -u /path/to/folder`

However, that will add files in subdirectories of that folder as well, which might not be what you want. If you don't want subdirectories and you are in a bash shell, you can try:

`git add /path/to/folder/*.*`

That command will add any file in a folder as long as those files follow the standard name.extension naming convention.

Comment: The OP asked how to `commit` only modified files. This answer is valid only if starting with no files in staging.

Answer (score 3):

To commit only already tracked files:

```
git add -u
```

This will also take any files that have been deleted, but will not add newly created files.

Comment: I see. But do that take account the current directory ? See my modified question ?

Comment: I see your modified question, and any `git add` command can be followed by a file path, regardless of arguments.